# Understanding extern storage specifier in C

Tags: c

I was going through Dennis Ritchie's book, The C programming language. In it, he says:

> In certain circumstances, the extern declaration can be omitted. If the definition of the
>   external variable occurs in the source file before its use in a particular function, then there is no
>   need for an `extern` declaration in the function.

I tried quick code as follows:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int n = 0;
int nn = 111;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n = 1;
    printf("n from main(): %d\n", n);   
    function1();         
    function2();         
}

void function1()
{
    extern int n;
    int nn;  //declaring without extern keyword, this should point to global nn as per Dennis, but that does not seem to happen
    int nnn; //declaring without extern keyword
    printf("n from function1(): %d\n", n);
    printf("nn from function1(): %d\n", nn);
    printf("nnn from function1(): %d\n", nnn);
    n = 10;
}

void function2()
{
    extern int n;
    int nn;  //declaring without extern keyword, this should point to global nn as per Dennis, but that does not seem to happen
    int nnn; //declaring without extern keyword
    printf("n from function2(): %d\n", n);
    printf("nn from function2(): %d\n", nn);
    printf("nnn from function2(): %d\n", nnn);
}

int nnn = 222 ;
```

Below is sample output:

```
n from main(): 1
n from function1(): 0
nn from function1(): 1955388784
nnn from function1(): 6422476
n from function2(): 10
nn from function2(): 1955388784
nnn from function2(): 6422476
```

Notice what both functions `function1()` and `function2()` printed above. I guess, as per Dennis' statement, both should have referred global `nn` and should have printed `111`. But that did not happen.

(You can try running code [here](https://onlinegdb.com/B1T3VY5hS))

Is it because the version about which Dennis is talking differs from the one using?
Am on `MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-5`.

Comment: Any variable declared in curly braces belongs to that scope

Comment: You're shadowing (hiding) your globals with automatics.

Comment: @MadPhysicist  but if that variable is defined in global scope before the function definition, then non-extern declaration of that variable withing the function should refer to global variable. Isnt this what author is trying to imply from that statement?

Comment: `extern int n;` has no effect in both `function1` and `function2`. Refering to `n` in both of these functions will refer to the global `n` declared in line 2.

Comment: If there is no other code module there are no `extern` declarations needed.

Comment: *"then non-extern declaration of that variable withing the function should refer to global variable."* - that's not what Mr. Richie, nor the language standard,  says.

Comment: I just wanted to know whether it should print `111` as per the author. Now I realized, author is saying "before its **use**". But by "use", he meant "use without (re)definition inside function"

Comment: Note that GCC has the option `-Wshadow` to report on local variables that shadow global variables (or other local variables at an outer scope within a function).  It isn't activated by `-Wall` or `-Wextra` — it can be a good option to use.  You should usually avoid 'nested externs' where you have an `extern` declaration in the scope of a function.  Generally, extern functions and variables should be declared by a header included at file scope, so that you can ensure consistency.  The `-Wnested-externs` option in GCC will warn about these.

Comment: @WeatherVane can you explain a bit more "if  there is no other code module there are no `extern` declarations needed." Dennis says if variable is declared before function, we dont need `extern` declaration inside that function if it needs to access that global variable.

Comment: Well yes, if the (global) variable is defined in in the same module then you can avoid `extern` by making it visible before it is needed, in the same way that you don't need a function prototype if the function is defined before it is called. But if you are going to define the variable or function in a different module then you *must* declare them.

Answer (score 4):

> , then there is no need for an extern declaration in the function.

Here what Dennis Ritchie saying is that, If definition of nn varibale is already occured in source file then now in `function1()` and `funcation2()` you do not need to declare variable as `extern` again, like (`extern int nn;`) you can directly use them.

But by doing `int nn;` in your `funcation1()` you are defining one another local variable. Which is complete different variable.

Answer (score 2):

The keyword extern is used with objects to reference objects that have file scope.

This declaration in your functions

```
int nn;  //declaring without extern keyword, this should point to global nn as per Dennis, but that does not seem to happen
```

has a block scope. So it is a definition of a local variable.. It does not have linkage.

The quote you provided means that if there is a definition of a file scope variable then it has external or internal linkage. So there is no need to use the keyword extern

For example

```
//…

int n = 10;  // definition of a variable with external linkage

void f()
{
    printf( "n = %d\n", n );
}

//...
```

Comment: This answer is poorly phrased in several regards. “The keyword extern is used with objects to reference objects that have file scope” is in the area of the correct behavior but is not correct. The behavior of `extern` is complicated, but this appears to be referring to the rule in C 2018 6.2.2 4, which says that a declaration with `extern` when a prior declaration is visible has the same linkage as the prior declaration (if it has internal or external linkage) or has external linkage (if the prior declaration has no linkage). If there is a prior declaration with file scope,…

Comment: … this will result either in the identifier referring to the same object or in undefined behavior, depending on circumstances. But, if there is no prior declaration with file scope, the declaration is still allowed but clearly cannot cause the identifier to refer to the same object as a prior declaration with file scope. Also, objects cannot have file scope because they cannot have scope. Identifiers have scope; objects do not.

Comment: Regarding the declaration `int nn;`: To be clear to readers who are just learning this, it should be made explicit that this declaration behaves differently inside a function (technically: inside a block) than outside a function.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be misinterpreting the last part of the statement that "there is no need for an `extern` **declaration** in the function" to mean "there is no need for an `extern` **keyword** in the function."

What Dennis is saying is that `extern int n;` in your functions is equivalent to not declaring `n` *at all*. `extern int n;` is *not* equivalent to `int n;`, e.g. in `main`.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to know whether it should print `111` as per the author. Now I realized, author is saying "...before its **use**..." and by "use", he meant "use without (re)definition inside function".

If we define variable again inside function without `extern`, it will create local variable for function.

(Dont know if I should answer my own question, may be others will correct me if am wrong in this understanding again.)

Answer (score 1):

You're completely misunderstanding Mr. Richie. He's saying that this:

```
int n;

void foo()
{
    n = 42;
}
```

requires no `extern` because the referenced variable `n` is defined *before* the function, `foo`, that uses it.

Were the code like this:

```
void foo()
{
    n = 42;
}

int n;
```

the compiler now has no idea what you're talking about when using `n` in the body of `foo`. There is no `n` until later, but the compiler has no idea that there ever *will* be.

You can address this by:

```
extern int n;

void foo()
{
    n = 42;
}

int n;
```

Now, when compiling `foo`, the compiler knows there is some `int` called `n` ... somewhere. Doesn't know where yet, and frankly doesn't care. Likewise, this will also work:

```
void foo()
{
    extern int n;
    n = 42;
}

int n;
```

That's all he's trying to say. Your code and comments seem to think that by doing this:

```
void foo()
{
    int n;
    n = 42;
}

int n;
```

the `n` in `foo` will magically resolve to the outer `n`. That isn't how the language works. All this does is make the code compile because now the compiler sees an `n` that fulfills usage for `n = 42`. It's an *automatic* variable (lifetime to the `{` scope `}` in which it is declared). It has absolutely nothing to do with the `int n;` outside that scope (but can easily shadow (hide) the name `n` if you're not careful. That is exactly what is happening in your code.